# A bound for the series of the Fourier transform.

Tags: fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let $f$ be an integrable function on $[-\pi,\pi]$ satisfying that  $f^{\prime}\in L^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$.

How can I show that

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}|\hat{f}(n)|\leq C(\|f\|_{1}+
\|f^{\prime}\|_{2})$$

where

$$\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-inx}dx.$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are missing $f(x)$ inside the integral.

Comment: Apply Cauchy-Schwarz to $\sum_{n  \ne 0} \frac{1}{|n|} |n \hat{f}(n)|$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my answer is too complicated. But I use the stuff that I know to prove the inequality. First, if we knew that $f\in L^2$, then it has an absolutely continuous representative with which we can perform partial integration. So, let us prove first that $f\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. For this, on $D := \{\varphi' : \varphi\in C_0^\infty(-\pi,\pi)\}$ define the functional $F(\phi) := \int_{-\pi}^\pi f\phi\,dx$. Since
$$
\left|\int_{-\pi}^\pi f\varphi'\,dx\right| = \left|\int_{-\pi}^\pi f'\varphi\,dx\right|\,\le\,\|f'\|_2\|\varphi\|_2\,\le\,\|f'\|_2\|\varphi'\|_2,
$$
the functional $F$ is continuous w.r.t. the $L^2$-norm and hence has a continuous extension $\tilde F$ on $L^2$. By the Riesz representation theorem, $\tilde F(g) = \langle g,\overline{f_0}\rangle$ with some $f_0\in L^2$. Thus, for $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(-\pi,\pi)$ we obtain
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f\varphi'\,dx = F(\varphi') = \tilde F(\varphi') = \langle\varphi',\overline{f_0}\rangle = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f_0\varphi'\,dx.
$$
And this proves $f = f_0 + const\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$.

Now, we can assume that $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$. For $n\neq 0$ we have
\begin{align*}
\hat f(n)
&= \frac 1 {2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}\,dx = -\frac 1 {2\pi in}\left(\left[f(x)e^{-inx}\right]_{-\pi}^\pi - \int_{-\pi}^\pi f'(x)e^{-inx}\,dx\right)\\
&= \frac 1 {2\pi in}\big[f(\pi)-f(-\pi)\big] + \frac{1}{in}\widehat{f'}(n).
\end{align*}
Hence, if $f$ is periodic, then
$$
\sum_{n\neq 0}|\hat f(n)| = \sum_{n\neq 0}\frac 1 n|\widehat{f'}(n)|\,\le\,\left(\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac 1 {n^2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n\neq 0}|\widehat{f'}(n)|^2\right)^{1/2}\,\le\,\frac\pi{\sqrt 3}\|f'\|_2.
$$
If $f$ is not periodic, then $|\hat f(n)|$ is not summable and the claim is false.

Comment: Why do you need $C^\infty_c$ ?

 $f' \in L^1([-\pi,\pi]) \supset L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ so $f(x) = C+\int_0^x f'(t)dt$ is absolutely continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$. 

Let $g(x) = f(x) - (f(\pi)-f(-\pi)) \{\frac{x+\pi}{2\pi}\}$ and $2\pi$-periodize. Then $g' \in L^2_{loc}$ and on $[-\pi,\pi], g' = f'-\frac{f(\pi)-f(-\pi)}{2\pi}$ therefore you can apply Cauchy-Schwarz $\sum_{n \ne 0}\frac{1}{|n|} |n \hat{g}(n)| \le C \|g'\|_{L^2([-\pi,\pi])}\le C(\|f'\|_{L^2(-\pi,\pi)}+A|f(\pi)-f(-\pi)|)$.

Comment: @reuns: 1. You are right that $\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt$ is abs. continuous. But how do I know that it equals $f$ (up to a constant)? This I need to check on $C_0^\infty$ functions. 2. What is $\{\frac{x+\pi}{2\pi}\}$?